# 'termstrc' was removed from CRAN, tried installing from .tar file - how do I install 'termstrc' I need it for another program

Tags: r

```
* installing *source* package 'termstrc' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'termstrc'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/termstrc'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/DANIEL~1/DOWNLO~1/termstrc_1.3.7 (1).tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build R packages from source, you need to have the proper tools like compiler etc. installed. You seem to be using Windows, which is particularly difficult in that respect. The necessary tools have therefore been collected as Rtools package: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. You will have to install that in order to build the package.

Comment: Ralf, thanks! With the latest version of R 3.5.1 installed and the non-frozen version of Rtools I was able compile termstrc_1.3.7. There were many package dependencies I needed to add, including a binary package which also needed to be compiled with Rtools. Compiling that additional binary actually took about as long as the entire R install. Rtools is magic.